# Black Jack Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to write a black jack program in Eclipse and I'm having an issue when the program deals an Ace. I asked the user if they want the Ace to be worth 1 or 11. It does that, but when I type in a value, it gives an error message

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at PlayBlackJack.main(PlayBlackJack.java:72)"
```

Could someone help with that? I have a separate class that if the random card generated is an ace, it returns the value of 11. Here's that part of the code

Update: It adds the value of the Ace to the user's total. But after an Ace is dealt and the user chooses a value, no matter what the total is, it stops the users turn and goes to the dealer. How can I correct this? Also another issues I am having is After the user says 'no' to wanting another card, it goes to the dealer and works fine, but then when asking the user if they want to play again, it goes into an infinite loop and starts throwing out random cards. How can I correct this issue also?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class PlayBlackJack {

```
public final static int MAXCARDS=52;
//declaring the constant maxcards to be 52
//since there are 52 cards in the deck
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd=new Scanner (System.in);


    String printRules;
    //check to see if the user wants to see the rules or not
    String more;
    //variable used to see if the user would like to play the game
    String next;
    //variable used to see if the user would like another card
    int dealerTotal, userTotal;
    //keeps track of the user's total and the dealer's total
    int wins=0, losses=0;
    //variables used to keep track of the user's wins and losses
    int card = 0;

    System.out.println("                Welcome to Black Jack!");
    System.out.println("Would you like to see the rules? Type yes or no");
    //If yes, rules printed, if no, rules not printed
    printRules=kbd.nextLine();
    printRules=printRules.toUpperCase();
    if (printRules.charAt(0)=='Y')
    {
        (print rules)
        System.out.println("Now lets play!\n\n\n");

    }


        System.out.println("Would you like to play a game of Black Jack?");
        more=kbd.nextLine();
        more=more.toUpperCase();

        next="Yes";
        while (!more.isEmpty() && more.charAt(0)=='Y')
        {
            System.out.println("The game begins with this your first card:");
            userTotal=0;
            dealerTotal=0;


            while (!next.isEmpty() && next.charAt(0)=='Y')
            {
                card=PickACard.findCardValue();



                if (card==11)

                {
                    System.out.println("Would you like the Ace to be a 1 or 11?");
                    int aceValue=kbd.nextInt();

                        while (aceValue!=1 && aceValue!=11)
                        {
                            System.out.println("You did not enter a 1 or 11");
                            aceValue=kbd.nextInt();
                        }
                    card=aceValue;

                }

                userTotal=userTotal+card;

                System.out.println("You're total is " +userTotal);


                if (userTotal>21)
                {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, You lose");
                    losses++;
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
                    next="No";
                    more=kbd.nextLine();
                    more=more.toUpperCase();

                }
                else 
                {
                System.out.println("Would you like another card?");
                next=kbd.nextLine();
                next=next.toUpperCase();
                }

            }


            while (dealerTotal<=userTotal && userTotal<21)
            {
                System.out.println("Now it's the dealer's turn");
                int card1=0;
            card1=PickACard.findCardValue();

            if (card1==11)
            {       
                int aceValue1;

                        if (dealerTotal+11>21)
                        {
                            aceValue1=1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            aceValue1=11;
                        }
                    card1=aceValue1;

            }

            dealerTotal=dealerTotal+card1;
            System.out.println("The dealer's total is "+dealerTotal);


            if (dealerTotal==userTotal && userTotal<21)
            {
                losses++;
                System.out.println("Sorry, you lose. Would you like to play again?");
                more=kbd.nextLine();
                more=more.toUpperCase();

            }

            if (dealerTotal>21)
                {
                    wins++;
                    System.out.println("You Win! Would you like to play again?");
                    more=kbd.nextLine();
                    more=more.toUpperCase();

                }
                /*else
                {
                    losses++;
                    System.out.println("You lose. Would you like to play again?");
                    more=kbd.nextLine();
                    more=more.toUpperCase();

                }*/
            }


        }



        System.out.println("You won "+wins+" game(s) and lost "+losses+" game(s)");
        kbd.close();
```

}

}

Comment: which is the line number 72

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: How is `kbd` declared?

Comment: What was the previous call using `kbd` before `kbd.nextLine();`? And have you considered checking if `String.isEmpty()`?

Comment: I update the answer and kbd.nextLine();  Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that because you are using `kbd.nextInt()` to get the Ace value there is a new line character is left in the buffer so when the loop goes around `kbd.nextLine()` returns new line character and not Y that might be causing an issue with `more.charAt(0)` You might have to add an extra `kbd.nextLine();` to get rid the new line character. Also as Elliot Frisch pointed out you should check if the string is empty in the while control statement.

```
while(!more.isEmpty() && more.charAt(0) == 'y')
{
}
```

I guess `next.charAt(0)` is showing the error.  You can try to do `kbd.nextLine();` right before you ask would you like another game and also check if next is not empty.

```
 while(!next.isEmpty() && more.charAt(0) == 'y')
    {
    }
```

Try this

```
System.out.println("Sorry, You lose");
losses++;
System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
next="No";
kbd.nextLine(); // to flush out new line character
more=kbd.nextLine();
more=more.toUpperCase();
```

You can also use nextLine() and parse it to int that will avoid the new line character issue.

```
aceValue = Integer.parseInt(kbd.nextLine());
```

Comment: Thank you all! With your help I was able to correct the program and it is now working properly! Thank you so much!

Comment: That's great!  Please please accept the answer if it was correct.   Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell which line is line 72 of your code, but I can tell you that it's pretty likely based on what you've given us that somehow either your `more` or `next` variables are becoming empty strings (i.e. "").  If you try and call `charAt(0)` for a 0-length `String`, you'll get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: This is what I get when the program runs and it deals an Ace. And like 63 and 72 are the two while loops statements: `Would you like another card?
yes
The card is the Ace of Hearts
Would you like the Ace to be a 1 or 11?
11
You're total is 29
Sorry, You lose
Would you like to play again?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at PlayBlackJack.main(PlayBlackJack.java:63)`

Comment: I suspect that @Yan is on to something with his answer.  It looks like you may be consuming the readable characters from `kbd`, but not consuming the newline character itself.